# Vue Resource with Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, api, basic-authentication, vuejs2

I wrote a method in Vue 2.0 with Vue Resource which connects to an API with Basic Authentication.

```
getCountries: function()
{
      options = {
          headers: 
          {
            'type'                        : 'GET',
            'Authorization'               : 'Basic c3VyZWJ1ZGR5LWFwaS11c2VyOkFwaTQzMjJTdXJlYg==',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'dataType'                    : "json"
          }
      }
      this.$http.get('http://surebuddy.azurewebsites.net/Api/Products', [options])
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.body);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

When I run this in the browser I simply get a **"403 (Forbidden)"** error message in the console.

With these authorisation credentials in Postman I can perfectly connect and receive data. I have a feeling that I'm incorrectly passing the Authorization in the header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js log API endpoint response with vue-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962114/vue-js-log-api-endpoint-response-with-vue-resource)

Comment: Have you verified in your browser console for the actual Request that is sent to your API? Is it really provisioned with your headers? See last Leandro comment regarding apache httpd-vhosts.conf `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*, Authorization"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://surebuddy.azurewebsites.net/Api/Products',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: 
    {
        Authorization: 'Basic [your auth key in encoded in base64 here]'
    }
}
this.$http(options).then((response) => {
            //...
});
```

> I've tested it locally and it worked with your auth key and url. Consider
>   replacing your auth key with a placeholder and change your basic auth
>   credentials.