# Vue-resource headers are not passed

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to send a simple POST request through vue-resource. It requires a specifi header, which I'm passing though the headers option, but i'm still getting a 401 error, with a missing header response.

I followed every step for the vue-resource configuration, here is the post request

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      quote: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getQuote () {
      this.$http
        .post('https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=movies',
        {},
        {
          headers: {
            'X-Mashape-Key': 'x1TtXXYZYemshmluWEEZ3mqnx78yp1RtL6gjsnoxDbxhy4TBoT',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        })
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result.body.quote)
        this.quote = result.body.quote
        this.author = result.body.author
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js log API endpoint response with vue-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962114/vue-js-log-api-endpoint-response-with-vue-resource)

Comment: Have you verified in your browser console for the actual Request that is sent to your API? Is it really provisioned with your headers? See last Leandro comment regarding apache httpd-vhosts.conf `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*, Authorization"`